# What's the proper terminology for 32- vs 64- "bits"

Tags: terminology

I'm crystal clear on different architectures providing 32-bit or 64-bit registers and how that all works out at a low level.  However, one thing has always eluded me.. specific terminology for whether you're 32- or 64- bit.  For example:

`string XXX;`

if(architecture == i386)
  XXX = "32";
else if(architecture == x86_64)
  XXX = "64";

... go on to use variable XXX ...

So, what would I name my variable?  Not architecture.  Not "bits".  Not "bus width" or "register width" (that would seem quite out of place I think)

So what would this variable be named and what would someone say in conversation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd call it wordSize = "xx", I'd say 'word size'.

Comment: I considered that, perhaps it is right, but that conflicts with for 16-bit which is widely considered to be the word size of x86 architectures.  For example on x86-64 a 64-bit register operation is actually done with "pushq" with q meaning quad-word (16 * 4 = 64).  Just because x86 is ridiculous doesn't mean you're wrong, but it's a spin on things IMO

Comment: @Nektarios Haha you definitely know a lot more about this than I do. I think that there is more than one right answer to this question though.

Answer (score 3):

I thought of "pointer size", since the first relevant thing about 32-bit vs 64-bit is how much memory the application/OS can address.

But pretty much any such terminology is going to diverge from what you would say in conversation, since everybody mostly says "32-bit" and "64-bit" (and sometimes "x86" and "x64").

How about just `architectureBitLength`?

Comment: I think you nailed the conversation part, that it's just going to be "yeah that code is 32 bit" or "that driver is screwed up for 64 bit" although I just feel like such an idiot saying those things because "64-bit" is really an adjective and that's shoehorning it in to being a noun.  I'm not the grammar police or anything and the meaning is (probably) understood but it's still kind of goofy

Comment: I don't think it's become a noun. It's implicit (in saying and understanding) that "xx-bit" is still an adjective because when you say stuff like that there's an implicit noun for context: "that driver is screwed up for 64-bit [operating systems]"; "you should instead install [the] 32-bit [version of whatever we're talking about]". Dropping redundant context happens all the time. Might try asking on English.SE or Programmers.SE (or migrating this)?

Answer (score 1):

[This Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address#Word_size_versus_address_size) hints at "word size" but also brings in the term "address size", which spills into the term "address space".
Unfortunately, many systems use the term "word" to mean "a 16 bit data value", which confuses things.
The 1st paragraph of [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29) seems to solidly confirm user686605's position: "word size".

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the term "Bit width". I know it's not literally what this is, but people seem to understand it easier.

Answer (score -1):

Bitness is my preferred terminology.